# Need assistance finding errors in this program

Tags: prolog

Can someone help me find the errors in this code. I am getting two compile errors.
These are the errors.

/home/cg/root/9003115/main.pg:8:15: syntax error: ] or operator expected in list
/home/cg/root/9003115/main.pg:11:9: syntax error: ] or operator expected in list

```
  pivot(Before, After) :-
    length(Before, R), length(After, R), 
    \+ (Before = After),
    one(Before, After),
    two(Before, After).

one([H|T], [H|TT]) :- temp(T, TT).
one(List, [_|T) :- one(List, T).

two([H|T], [H|TT]) :- temp(T,TT).
two([_|T, List) :- two(T, List).

temp([],[]).
temp(_,[]).
temp([],_).
temp([H|T], [H|TT]) :- temp(T,TT).
```

Comment: you have 2 typos, one on line 8 and the other on line 11. Where it says `[H|T` it should say `[H|T]` and where it says `[_|T` it should say `[_|T]`.  Just as the error message suggests, you have to end a list with `]`

Comment: And please, write `temp([_|_], []).` in place of `temp(_,[]).)` and `temp([],[_|_]).` in place of `temp([],_).` otherwise you will get extra redundant solutions sometime.